# Why is `\strut` working in these scenarios?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, boxes, strut

`\strut` seems to be a powerful command to get the interlinear spacing correct; particularly, when working with text in `\parbox`s or `minipage`s.  But it's also nice in contexts in which LaTeX is setting the text in an *unexpected* place.

Here's a MWE which illustrates two situations in which `\strut` is the quick and easy method to get the interlinear or textual alignment correct.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[width=7.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{3in}
  \hspace*{\fill}Naive Approach\hspace*{\fill}

  \vspace{1cm}

  \noindent
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    first  & short text                                                         \\
    second & \parbox[t]{2.25in}{By putting a long line here I get bad spacing.} \\
    third  & short text                                                         \\
    fourth & spacing                                                            \\
    fifth  & short text                                                         \\
  \end{tabular}

  \vspace{1cm}

  \leavevmode\vadjust{
    \noindent
    \raisebox{\dimexpr0.5\totalheight\relax}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[0pt][r]{Hello}}
  }%
  \lipsum[1]

  \vspace{1cm}

  On this side of things, the placement of \verb-Hello- just isn't easily
  gotten correct whether I substitute 

  \vspace{0.5cm}

  \centering
  \verb|\dimexpr0.5\totalheight\relax| 

  by
  \verb|\depth| or just plain \verb|0pt|.

  \vspace{0.5cm}

  \textbf{Note:} if I replace \verb-Hello- by \verb-Why- and then raise
  the box by \verb-\depth- then things appear to be visually aligned correctly.

\end{minipage}\hspace*{\fill}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{3in}
  \hspace*{\fill}Better spacing with \verb=\strut=\hspace*{\fill}

  \vspace{1cm}

  \noindent
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    first  & short text                                                               \\
    second & \parbox[t]{2.25in}{By putting a long line here I get bad spacing.\strut} \\ 
    third  & short text                                                               \\
    fourth & spacing                                                                  \\
    fifth  & short text                                                               \\
  \end{tabular}

  \vspace{1cm}

  \leavevmode\strut\vadjust{
    \noindent
    \raisebox{\dp\strutbox}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[0pt][r]{Hello}}
  }%
  \lipsum[1]


\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I've seen the answers posted at [What's the difference between \strut, \mathstrut and \vphantom?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41192/22413) and [Spacing between items containing a parbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45044/22413).  They're helpful in understanding when to use `\strut`.  I've looked at how `\strut` is defined.  But I'm still in the dark about how `\strut` actually accomplishes what it does.

Could someone take the time to explain how it is that using `\strut` achieves the correct effect?  Or point me in the right direction?

**NOTE**
I've also seen [this explanation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21834/22413) but other than restating the definition, I'm still unclear about why it's working in the situations I've provided above.

**UPDATE**

After considering the example @Werner provided using `\fbox`s to show the depth created by `\strut`, I decided I should try something similar to illustrate my situation involving `\vstrut`.  Unfortunately, it wasn't as simple as just placing my example into an `\fbox`.  Basically the content disappears.
But I prevailed.  In the following MWE I test out three different scenarios with three cases each.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\aestrut}{\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\rule[\dimexpr-0.3\baselineskip\relax]{0.4pt}{\dimexpr\baselineskip\relax}}}
\newcommand{\visibleStrutAndBaseline}{\aestrut\rule[-0.4pt]{1cm}{0.4pt} Followed by text}
\newcommand{\aehline}{\rule[-0.4pt]{1cm}{0.4pt}}

\newcommand{\aecontent}[1]{\aehline\hspace{\dimexpr-1cm+0.25em}#1}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

  \visibleStrutAndBaseline --- using No strut
  {\leavevmode\vadjust{\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\aecontent{Text}}}}

  \vspace{0.25cm}

  \visibleStrutAndBaseline --- using Strut but not raised
  {\leavevmode\strut\vadjust{\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\aecontent{Text}}}}

  \vspace{0.25cm}

  \visibleStrutAndBaseline --- using Strut and raised by depth of strut
  {\leavevmode\strut\vadjust{\raisebox{\dp\strutbox}[0pt][0pt]{\aecontent{Text}}}}


  %%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  \vspace{1cm}

  \visibleStrutAndBaseline --- using No strut
  {\leavevmode\vadjust{\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\aecontent{Ziggy}}}}

  \vspace{0.25cm}

  \visibleStrutAndBaseline --- using Strut but not raised
  {\leavevmode\strut\vadjust{\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\aecontent{Ziggy}}}}

  \vspace{0.25cm}

  \visibleStrutAndBaseline --- using Strut and raised by depth of strut
  {\leavevmode\strut\vadjust{\raisebox{\dp\strutbox}[0pt][0pt]{\aecontent{Ziggy}}}}

  %%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  \vspace{1cm}

  \visibleStrutAndBaseline\rule[-2ex]{2pt}{3ex} --- using No strut
  {\leavevmode\vadjust{\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\aecontent{Deep}}}}

  \vspace{0.25cm}

  \visibleStrutAndBaseline\rule[-2ex]{2pt}{3ex} --- using Strut but not raised
  {\leavevmode\strut\vadjust{\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\aecontent{Deep}}}}

  \vspace{0.25cm}

  \visibleStrutAndBaseline\rule[-2ex]{2pt}{3ex} --- using Strut and raised by depth of strut
  {\leavevmode\strut\vadjust{\raisebox{\dp\strutbox}[0pt][0pt]{\aecontent{Deep}}}}

\end{document}
```

The scenarios involve the depth of the main line of text and the depth of the text in the `\vadjust`.  So, in **scenario one** the depth of the `\vadjust` content is **zero**.  In **scenario two** there is a nontrivial depth for this content.  In the **third scenario** I've created a *deep* depth.

For each scenario there are three cases:
The **case one** is to consider what happens when `\strut` is not used.  **Case two** is to use `\strut` but not raise the contents of the `\vadjust`.  And the **third case** illustrates raising the content by the depth of `\strut`.

In all *scenarios* and *cases* I use a visible strut to mimic  `\strut`, which I've set to zero height and depth so as not to inadvertently disturb the vertical spacing.

[image]

This example helped me see two things:  **first** was where exactly `\vadjust` is placing the text:  Sure enough, others have been saying it's placed between the lines.  And that is certainly true.  Per correction by @DavidCarlisle : it seems to be placed so that the *TOP*  of the `\vadjust`'s content is aligned with the *BOTTOM* (not the baseline) of the box for the line from within which `\vadjust` was called.
The **second** things I was able to see was that, as long as the main text does not have any boxes with *wild* depths, then `\strut` will be sufficiently deep to affect the correct depth to get the desired alignment.

Comment: I greatly appreciate the answers I'm getting, but I don't think I've properly formed the question, or I'm just totally not getting something.  At any rate, I'm working on an update to the question that will better clarify where my confusion is coming from.

Comment: I think my real confusion revolves around how `\leavevmode`, `\vadjust` and `\strut` are all interacting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the comments on the on the other answers, it seems like you want to concentrate on

```
 \leavevmode\strut\vadjust{%
    \noindent
    \raisebox{\dp\strutbox}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[0pt][r]{Hello}}
  }%
```

The first `\leavevmode` isn't really needed as `\strut` is defined to get into horizontal mode, however it does no harm and makes it clearer that the code needs horizontal mode.
Then comes the `\strut` this is important and we'll come back to that. 
Then `\vadjust`: the content of `\vadjust` is evaluated immediately (like `\vbox`) but the resulting vertical material is not boxed but inserted into the vertical list that will be later constructed from the lines in the paragraph.

The intention of the code is to make `hello` aligned to the baseline of the previous box, but the vadjust material is inserted directly into the list not forced to baseline spacing so to align to the baseline of the previous box you need to back up by the depth of the previous box. the "previous box" has not yet been constructed, it consists of whatever text ends on the line that has the vadjust node If that line had arbitrary text its depth would not be known. However as `\strut` was added and this had bigger depth than any letter or other normal text it is reasonable to assume the depth of the line is the depth of strutbox.

So `\raisebox{\dp\strutbox}` gets you back to the baseline of the previous line.

This will fail if you put some deep inline math or an inline tabular in the line, but if you need to deal with that you need a more complicated two pass measuring scheme.

Comment: So it seems that I was on the right track in my update.  Thank you for this explanation.

Comment: @A.Ellett Oh I'd missed that update yes but not this: But, it seems to be placed so that the baseline of the \vadjust's content is aligned with the BOTTOM (not the baseline) The _top_ of the vadjust material is placed after the _bottom_ of the previous line, Here you are smashing the height of the insert with the `0pt` makebox arguments so you get baseline but try `\vadjust{\hbox{hello}}`

Comment: Argh!  How right.  I forgot that I was smashing things.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 8):

The main issue here deals with the bounding boxes associated with the contents. Some elements have different depths than others, most notably from text *without* descenders. For example, `Hello` has no depth, while `spacing` has some. The idea behind `\strut` is to ensure that `\strut Hello` and `\strut spacing` (for example) cover the same ground vertically.

A quick example of this is visible when you view this MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\ddd}[1]{\fbox{\strut#1}\,\fbox{#1}}% Show the difference in bounding boxes
\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}% For this example
\begin{document}

Letters: \ddd{a}\ \ddd{b}\ \ddd{p} \ddd{Q}

\bigskip

Words: \ddd{Hello}\ \ddd{spacing}

\end{document}
```

Is can be seen, the bounding boxes of these letters/words are vertically equivalent to one another, even though they each may have different descenders/ascenders. More specifically, `\strut` ensures at least a 70% `\baselineskip` in terms of height, and 30% `\baselineskip` in depth in the prevailing font. From `\strutbox`'s definition (used by `\strut`) in the [LaTeX kernel](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx) as part of `\set@fontsize`:

```
\setbox\strutbox\hbox{%
  \vrule\@height.7\baselineskip
        \@depth.3\baselineskip
        \@width\z@}%
```

So, specific to your case, you can see that the `\strut` inside the `\parbox` increases the depth of the box, and therefore the skip from one line to the next (see the difference in the bounding boxes related to `spacing` above).

The second comparison to `Hello` is somewhat bizarre in your particular case. In the first you raise it based on height+depth (or `\totalheight`) while in the second you raise it based on depth only (`\dp`). Since `Hello` has height, the first raise is non-zero, while it is zero in the second, since `Hello` has zero depth.

Also see, as reference, [How to keep a constant `\baselineskip` when using `minipage`s (or `\parbox`es)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34971/5764)

Comment: I think I should have left out the example of the `\parbox`.  Though I included it because I couldn't figure out how to get the solution at [the link you provided](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34971/how-to-keep-a-constant-baselineskip-when-using-minipages-or-parboxes) to work in a `tabular` environment.

Comment: I think my real confusion arises from the second example with `\vadjust` where the depth of `\strut` seems to me like it should be insufficient to raise the box to properly align with the remaining text.

Comment: @A.Ellett: Instead of `\vadjust{\raisebox..\makebox..Hello}` you can just use `\llap{Hello}` The output is the same.

Comment: Not quite.  I'm actually interested in placing text in the margin.  Compare the effects in this example: `Here is some text {\leavevmode\vadjust{\raisebox{0pt}{\makebox[0pt][r]{Hello}}}} is not the same as {\leavevmode\llap{Hello}}`

Comment: @A.Ellett: Placing text in the margin is sufficiently obtained via a single `\rlap`. I'm not sure why you need `\vadjust`.

Comment: It was a suggestion made by @DavidCarlisle [to a question I was asking](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113740/22413) about how to create my own custom margin notes.  I seem to need the \vadjust in order to get the proper calculation for the lengths needed to get my *notes* into the margins.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, what does `\strut` do? It simply produces an invisible rule whose height is 70% and the depth 30% of the current baselineskip.

A `\parbox[t]` makes a box as high as its first line; all the successive lines contribute to the depth. Thus, when a `\parbox[t]` is found, between the line in which it is and the next one, the `\lineskip` glue will be inserted (excluding the trivial case of a one line `\parbox[t]`). A fix for getting uniform spacing is thus to end the `\parbox[t]` with `\strut` and adding one in the next line. This will ensure (except in the case where lines are too high or deep) that the baselines are `\baselineskip` apart (using the fact that the `\lineskip` glue is usually zero).

This is shown in your first example, with the `\parbox` nested in a `tabular`. There's no need to add a `\strut` in the following row, because rows in a `tabular` are kept apart from each other exactly by struts.

The second example is more contorted. The material in `\vadjust` should be vertical material and not horizontal material, which causes however horizontal mode to start. The material is added *between* lines and, since it contains a box, it will contribute its height and depth (but no interline glue). You can check this by saying `\vadjust{Hello}` instead. So it doesn't provide a good illustration of `\strut` usage.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your statement that "there's no need to add a `strut` in the following row". It seems I needed it where it was placed.  Could you clarify what you meant?

Comment: @A.Ellett You don't need a strut in the row `third&short text`, because one is already provided by `tabular`.

Answer (score 0):

`\strut` makes an invisible vbox such, that it fills space between the baselines. Hence (in typical cases) the spacing is uniform.

Comment: I agree with you about the *typical* case.  But, where "Hello" is jutting out into the margin doesn't seem very *typical* to me.  And in this particular scenario it's much more a mystery to me why `\strut` is working than the other.

Comment: @A.Ellett Because "Hello" has zero depth. Hence `\strutbox`adds an additional depth and the lines are aligned.

Comment: But without a strut and without raising the box, "Hello" would be set between the lines.  As I understand it `\strut` would add invisible height and depth.  That might lead me to think that the correct value to pass to `\raisebox` would be something like `\dimexpr\dp\strutbox+\ht\strutbox\relax`.  But that would be wrong.  Given that `\raisebox{\depth}[0pt][0pt]{Why}` works and since "Hello" has zero depth, I would then naively think that `\raisebox{0pt}....` should do the trick, which it doesn't.